# fix results of javascript loop

Tags: javascript, ejs

I have this:

```
<% var arrayOfTimes = []; %>
 <% for (var i = 0; i <= 24; i++) { %>
   <% var n = i%2==0 ? i/2+':00' : (i+1)/2-1+':30'; %>
     <% if(n<10) %>
       <% n = ''+n; %>
       <% arrayOfTimes.push(n); %>
       <% console.log(arrayOfTimes); %>
     <% } %>
```

and it returns this:

```
[
  '0:00',  '0:30',  '1:00',
  '1:30',  '2:00',  '2:30',
  '3:00',  '3:30',  '4:00',
  '4:30',  '5:00',  '5:30',
  '6:00',  '6:30',  '7:00',
  '7:30',  '8:00',  '8:30',
  '9:00',  '9:30',  '10:00',
  '10:30', '11:00', '11:30',
  '12:00'
]
```

But now I want it to actually have 15-minute intervals. so it would return

```
[
  '0:00', '0:15', '0:30'
]
```

how would i do this based on the loop I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 48 iterations instead of 24. Then you can use `i%4` as the index into an array of minutes for the quarter hours.

```
<% var arrayOfTimes = []; %>
 <% for (var i = 0; i <= 48; i++) { %>
   <% var n = Math.floor(i/4) + [":00", ":15", ":30", ":45"][i%4]; %>
   <% if(n<10) %>
       <% n = ''+n; %>
   <% arrayOfTimes.push(n); %>
   <% console.log(arrayOfTimes); %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: awesome, thanks for your help :)